# Problem with JAXB and Hibernate3 illegal access

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb

I'm migrating a system from hibernate2 to hibernate 3 and i'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<init>()V from class com.sun.xml.bind.DefaultJAXBContextImpl
 at com.sun.xml.bind.DefaultJAXBContextImpl.<init>(DefaultJAXBContextImpl.java:73)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:39)
```

I have already searched in the hibernate migration guides and found nothing on this topic. Searching on google also proved no good. This error has been pesking me for some time already and I would like any kind of assistance.

Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look to code in here

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/DatatypeConverterImpl.java.html

You can see that constructor is protected, so for retrieving instance you should address theInstance (line 62), which has public access.

Comment: I see... Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry to ask, but you know where i might an example of this kind of implementation?
When i look at the servlet that causes the error, it doesn't have any reference do JAXB, since the one who throws the error is the Standard Wrappler.